# node inspect on google cloud console setup firewall

Tags: node.js, debugging, npm, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-networking

I am trying to setup the firewall for accessing node inspect using my local chrome browser.

Does anybody have a good short guide and which tcp protocol do I need to enable.

I have a firewall rule active where the compute instance enables tcp:80. It worked in the past of a http server. How do I know which port to use for node inspect and how to enable it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If found it myself. I have to use an ssh tunnel. https://nodejs.org/en/docs/guides/debugging-getting-started/#enabling-remote-debugging-scenarios

> Enabling remote debugging scenarios
>   We recommend that you never have the debugger listen on a public IP address. If you need to allow remote debugging connections we
>   recommend the use of ssh tunnels instead. We provide the following
>   example for illustrative purposes only. Please understand the security
>   risk of allowing remote access to a privileged service before
>   proceeding.
>
> Let's say you are running Node on remote machine, remote.example.com, that you want to be able to debug. On that
>   machine, you should start the node process with the inspector
>   listening only to localhost (the default).
>
> ```
>     $ node --inspect server.js
> ```
>
> Now, on your local machine from where you want to initiate a debug client connection, you can setup an ssh tunnel:
>
> ```
>     $ ssh -L 9221:localhost:9229 user@remote.example.com
> ```
>
> This starts a ssh tunnel session where a connection to port 9221 on your local machine will be forwarded to port 9229 on
>   remote.example.com. You can now attach a debugger such as Chrome
>   DevTools or Visual Studio Code to localhost:9221, which should be able
>   to debug as if the Node.js application was running locally.